# python html pop open

Tags: html, python-3.x, file-handling

I have written a Python program using Python 3.3. The output is saved as an HTML file. I want the HTML file to pop open automatically and show the results at the end of the program. Is there ay solution for this?
I'll appreciated your help.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
>>> import webbrowser
>>> webbrowser.get('/usr/bin/google-chrome %s').open('http://google.com')
True
```

**This will open the Chrome web browser with the Google's homepage.

Change the `url path` to the `file path` of the html page and use `file://{ followed by the html page path }`

```
>>> webbrowser.get('/usr/bin/google-chrome %s').open('file://the/path/to/the/html/page')
```

Updated:

Try:

```
>>> webbrowser.get('windows-default').open('{ url path for static html page }')
```

Reference: [python's webbrowser launches IE instead of default on windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916270/pythons-webbrowser-launches-ie-instead-of-default-on-windows-7)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried it out. No errors but still the browser doesn't pop open :(

Comment: @user3017348 - did you check for pop up blocker?