# Python Webbrowser - how to detect the users defult webbrowser

Tags: python, windows, python-webbrowser

i am trying to find the users defult web browser and webbrowser.open() is opening internet explorer.

```
        elif 'open browser' in statement:
            webbrowser.open("https://www.google.com")
            speak("your browser is now opening")
            time.sleep(5)
```

i would like to know how i can detect the users defult browser so it dosent always open google

Comment: What do you exactly want? You can open a certain browser with the `get` method. You can detect the default browser as well. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68292700/5541355) answer.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.