# webbrowser.open() in python

Tags: python, html

I have a python file `html_gen.py` which write a new `html` file `index.html` in the same directory, and would like to open up the `index.html` when the writing is finished.

So I wrote

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open("index.html");
```

But nothing happen after executing the .py file. If I instead put a code

```
webbrowser.open("http://www.google.com")
```

Safari will open google frontpage when executing the code.

I wonder how to open the local index.html file?

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5943706/771848

Comment: do you get an error if you call builtin `open('index.html')` ? It checks whether you can open the file for reading.

Comment: Cannot reproduce on Python 2.7.6, Ubuntu 14.04, Firefox 47.

Comment: webbrowser.open('index.html', new=2, autoraise=True) works fine, is the semi-colon breaking it?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Try specifying the "file://" at the start of the URL. Also, use the absolute path of the file:

```
import webbrowser, os
webbrowser.open('file://' + os.path.realpath(filename))
```

Comment: Note: Need to import the Python os module for this to work:  import os

Answer (score 7):

Convert the filename to url using [`urllib.pathname2url`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.pathname2url):

```
import os
try:
    from urllib import pathname2url         # Python 2.x
except ImportError: # Don't use just "except:"
    from urllib.request import pathname2url # Python 3.x

url = 'file:{}'.format(pathname2url(os.path.abspath('1.html')))
webbrowser.open(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

With latest versions of Python I believe that a better API to open a local file would be:

```
import webbrowser
import pathlib

webbrowser.open(pathlib.Path(target_as_str).as_uri())
```