# Is there any way to open python's data in a browser page without needing to create a server?

Tags: python, json, visual-studio-code

**Part 1 (solved from the help indicated in the comments of this question):**

I would like to open this JSON response print() in a page of my default browser (Chrome), as I have a JSON Viewer extension and I would like to study this data with an easier view than in the Visual Studio Code terminal.

Is there any simple method for this to be done without the need to create an html file with this data, create a specific server and only then be able to open it in the browser?

I tried to use the webbrowser but it just opened any page, it didn't open the data.

```
import requests
import json
import webbrowser
 
url="https://api.betfair.com/exchange/betting/json-rpc/v1"
header = { 'X-Application' : 'AAAAAAAAAAAAA', 'X-Authentication' : 'BBBBBBBBBBBB' ,'content-type' : 'application/json' }
 
jsonrpc_req='{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "SportsAPING/v1.0/listCompetitions", "params": {"filter":{"eventTypeIds": [1]}}, "id": 2}'
 
response = requests.post(url, data=jsonrpc_req, headers=header)
 
data = json.dumps(json.loads(response.text), indent=3)

webbrowser.open(data)
```

**Part 2:**

I'm trying to open a `.json` file by the browser so that I can analyze the data more easily, according to the tips in the comments, I started using the `webbrowser`, but when I try to open `.json` the page doesn't open and when I try to open it as `.txt` or `.html` the extension that improves the visualization of `JSON` in the browser, doesn't recognize the data and doesn't format for it.

How could I manage to do this?

My extension in Chrome:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/json-viewer/gbmdgpbipfallnflgajpaliibnhdgobh?hl=pt-BR

Github project extension:
https://github.com/tulios/json-viewer

I post my `Python` code here just to make it easier to see `print()`:

```
import requests
import json
 
url="https://api.betfair.com/exchange/betting/json-rpc/v1"
header = { 'X-Application' : 'AAAAAAAAAAAAA', 'X-Authentication' : 'BBBBBBBBBBBB' ,'content-type' : 'application/json' }
 
jsonrpc_req='{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "SportsAPING/v1.0/listCompetitions", "params": {"filter":{"eventTypeIds": [1]}}, "id": 2}'
 
response = requests.post(url, data=jsonrpc_req, headers=header)

with open("ApiBetfair.html", "w+", newline="", encoding="UTF-8") as f:
    data = json.dumps(json.loads(response.text), indent=3)
    f.write(data)

new = 2
webbrowser.open('file://' + os.path.realpath('ApiBetfair.html'),new=new)
```

Comment: You could create like a custom stream object that handles opening the browser and displaying the data pushed to it, then pass that as the `file=` argument to `print`. I just wouldn't use `print` here though. It isn't the right tool for the job.

Comment: You could store the JSON as a file and then open it in your browser using the [`webbrowser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html) module. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40905794/15873043), it should work for JSON as well.

Comment: write the data to a file and open that file in the browser

Comment: This seems like a great use-case for something like Flask

Comment: Hello @fsimonjetz how are you? Thank you very much for your comment, however when trying to open a file with .json format the browser does not open the page and when trying to open as .html the extensions that format the page to read JSON do not work. Would you help me? I will update the question with new editions! Extension I use (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/json-viewer/gbmdgpbipfallnflgajpaliibnhdgobh?hl=pt-BR)

Comment: @BrondbyIF Did you enable the local file option? On the [github page](https://github.com/tulios/json-viewer) of the add-on it says "Works on local files (if you enable this in chrome://extensions)".

Comment: Hi @fsimonjetz That was exactly it, I hesitated a lot in this detail, thank you very much! Could you create a short answer commenting on the two parts that helped me in the complete solution so that I can mark as a solution so as not to leave the question open? Thanks in advance. I don't want to delete the question because maybe someone else will need it in the future.

Comment: @BrondbyIF Glad to help and thank you, I appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the JSON in a local file and open it with the [`webbrowser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html) module. As we figured out in the comments above, it is necessary to [enable local file support](https://github.com/tulios/json-viewer) in `chrome://extensions` for the extension to work properly.

```py
import webbrowser

fp = "ApiBetfair.html"

with open(fp, "w+", newline="", encoding="UTF-8") as f:
    data = json.dumps(json.loads(response.text), indent=3)
    f.write(data)

new = 2 # open in new tab
webbrowser.open('file://' + os.path.realpath(fp),new=new)
```