# How do I run an html code in browser using Python 3.7?

Tags: python, html, browser

Got an HTML code stored in a variable in Python script, I need the browser to open with my HTML. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [webbrowser.open() in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22004498/webbrowser-open-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

You can do with many ways one of the below :

```
import os
import webbrowser

html = '<html>Hello World</html>'
path = os.path.abspath('sample.html')
url = 'file://' + path

with open(path, 'w') as f:
    f.write(html)
webbrowser.open(url)
```

Answer (score 1):

Save the following HTML to a file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Hello World!</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  <p>This is a HTML document!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Then add the following code to your python script:

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open("file://path/to/document.html")
```

Good luck.