# Script for opening up a Google search in a specific browser

Tags: python, search, browser

I want to google search a specific phrase using python program that too in a specific browser like Mozilla/google chrome.

```
import webbrowser

url = "https://www.google.com.tr/search?q={}".format("Raspberry Pi")    
webbrowser.open(url)
```

I read this script in some post but it always go for the default browser in the system, can't i select or specify a different browser.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/5916357/771848. Might be considered as duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use webbrowser.get('browser') to specify a browser.

```
import webbrowser
url = "https://www.google.com.tr/search?q={}".format("Raspberry Pi") 
b = webbrowser.get('lynx')
b.open(url)
```

Comment: It gives a error

raise Error("could not locate runnable browser")
Error: could not locate runnable browser

How to select proper name of the browser.

Comment: Try `webbrowser.get('firefox')`

Comment: @ragrawal3, the browser names are listed here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/webbrowser.html#webbrowser.register

Comment: i have tried both 'firefox' & 'mozilla' but it shows the same error

Comment: What OS are you using? Are Firefox and/or Mozilla installed? What browser do you get if you just say `webbrowser.open()`?

Comment: OS-Windows 8
Yes i do have firefox installed
I get internet Explorer by default