# Python webbrowser.open() does not open page in default browser

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

I am using PySide and need to open web-page in default system browser. Example of code below, however it run always IE browser:

```
import webbrowser

webbrowser.open(url_link)
```

What can it be an issue?

Comment: can you show us the url you are trying

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916270/pythons-webbrowser-launches-ie-instead-of-default-on-windows-7

Comment: Already tried every method from the link above... without success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple solution...

```
webbrowser.open('http://' + url_link)
```